# Prevent Word on Mac to automatically follow hyperlinks on click

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am developing a Word Add-in application that should work on Word application for both Windows and Mac. I have a problem specific to Word on Mac, while Word on Windows and Word online work as expected.

For business logic reasons my add-in application needs to create and update hyperlinks in the word document. The hyperlink gets updated once the user clicks on it in the document. However, the default behaviour of the Word on Mac is to automatically navigate user to the browser with the hyperlink URL, once he/she clicks on the hyperlink. Incidentally, if you press CMD + click on a Mac, you won't be navigated away from the application.

Is it possible to programatically (using Office/Word Api from the JS driven add-in application) prevent that kind of behaviour on hyperlinks when clicked?

If not, is it possible to capture and cancel the cursor click event on the hyperlink? Or capture it and maybe emit a new event which would simulate "CMD + click", with effect to not navigate from the document?